# Span and basis proofs

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose V is a vector space, $\vec v , \vec w \in V$ and $\vec v \ne \vec 0, \vec w \ne \vec 0$.

I am proving that $\vec w \in \langle \vec v \rangle$ iff $\vec v \in \langle \vec w \rangle$
I've started by saying that if $\vec w \in \langle \vec v \rangle$ then $\vec w = c \vec v$ where c is some scalar.Then $\vec v =  \frac{\vec w}{c}$ so $\vec w$ is in the span because its a linear combination of $\vec v$. Am I making any progress or have I just stated facts?

Also, I am proving if {$\vec v, \vec w$} is linearly independent then {$3\vec v , 2 \vec w$} is  a basis of {$\vec v, \vec w$}. So I am guessing this will stem off of a linear combination from the first part I'm proving. Like $3\vec v + 2\vec w = \vec 0$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of your steps are correct.  Good job.  Here's how to proceed with the rest of the proof:

After $\vec w=c\vec v$ you'll want to give an argument why $c\ne 0$ so that you can be sure dividing is allowed.  Then the consequence of $\vec v=\frac 1c\vec w$ is not that $\vec w\in \langle \vec v\rangle$, it's that $\vec v\in\langle \vec w\rangle$ because $\vec v$ is a linear combination of $\{\vec w\}$.  Hence $\vec w\in\langle \vec v\rangle \implies \vec v\in\langle \vec w\rangle$.  Then you have to make an argument in the other direction.

---

For the second part remember that a basis is a linearly independent spanning set.  So show that $\{3\vec v,2\vec w\}$ is a linearly independent set first.  Then show that it spans the same space as $\{\vec v,\vec w\}$.

Comment: Would the set up be similar to $3\vec v + 2\vec w = \vec 0$ b/c that's not linearly independent.

Comment: To prove that it's linearly independent you'll want to show that if $a$ and $b$ are two numbers such that $$a(3\vec v) + b(2\vec w) = \vec 0$$ then it must be the case that $a$ and $b$ are both $0$.

Comment: Oh ok that makes everything ten times easier to understand. Thank you for your help!